# Save hashmap in SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I need to save this  hashmap in SharedPreferences i tried to convert it into Json but it didn't work

```
 Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<String , String>() {{
                for(int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++ ) {
                    String id= userList.get(i).getId();
                    String name = userList.get(i).getName();
                    put(id, name);

                }
            }};
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String jsonString = gson.toJson(userMap);
            SessionManager sessionManager=new SessionManager(LoginActivity.this);
            sessionManager.saveMap(jsonString);
```

jsonString is returing null even usermap has data
I really need this to advance in my work appreciate anyhelp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gson is not recognizing the anonymous class that results from doing it that way.

Try initializing the map without using the `{{}}` construct.
e.g.

```java
Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<String , String>();

for(int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++ ) {
    String id= userList.get(i).getId();
    String name = userList.get(i).getName();
    put(id, name);
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(userMap);
SessionManager sessionManager=new SessionManager(LoginActivity.this);
sessionManager.saveMap(jsonString);
```

To convert this json back to a `Map<String, String>` you can use `TypeToken` as suggested [here](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-json-to-map).

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, String> nameEmployeeMap = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
```

Comment: Thank you bro it works but do you have an idea after i retrieve the json string how can i convert it back to hashmap

Comment: Yes, you have to use `TypeToken` to get it back in a type-safe way. Heads up, if the underlying json does not comply with this type token, it will raise an exception. I guess in your case it will always do.